# I get the error "unrecognized expression" when trying to select a class changing a variable

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
lastClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();
    
este = $('"'+("."+"a"+"."+lastClass)+'"');
```

Whenever it tries to get the value for este I get the error 'Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ".a.1"'. How can i fix it? I want to select the element with class "a" and "1".

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add more details and the code your trying to fix.

Comment: A class must not begin with a number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need quotes around the selector.

Change the selector to

```js
este = $("."+"a"+"."+lastClass);
```

or

```js
este = $(`.${a}.${lastClass}`);
```

Btw: Identifiers shouldn't start with a number.
[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

Comment: I use the number so i can add 1 to it to select other element

Comment: @JibriI You shouldn't. I added a quote of the W3C specification to my answer.

Comment: Ok, I will do it well for next time